# "Components" folder not included in project structure

Tags: next.js

I have a strange issue with nextJS.

I created new directory `components` in the root folder and added some test component files.

While I try to `import` it, the pass exists, but at localhost I have error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '../../components/admin/AdminBoLayout'
```

The path is correct, and the component works 100% (tested this code with another nextJs project).

**Why does problem appear?**

P.S. according to [this article](https://wityan.medium.com/next-js-project-structure-1531610bed71), `components` directory exist in nextJs project structure.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved: just `Ctrl+C` and `npm run dev` in terminal

(restart localhost)